Why doesn't Chrome permit usage of camera/mic even tho permission has been given?
I have granted permission for Chrome to access my microphone and camera both online and within my phone.

However, when I visit a website through Chrome that needs to use them, it will prompt me again. Despite selecting "Allow Access", it will deny me the privilege.

Even at this exact moment, I can select and use voice-to-text; I can use the microphone via my keyboard.
How do I fix this?

There are quite a few web pages online where you can test your webcam in your browser. Have you tried some of them and does your  camera work with them?

Yes, I read another post that named a site and I did verify thru it. I have not done others beyond that tho.
